# Bootstarp 4 - how to change order of cols in different rows for mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

I need to make a different order for bootstrap col for the mobile. I found many stack overflow question regrading this topic but i did not see any topic that is related to changing the order of cols that are on different rows.

```html
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-around mb-5">
  <div id="selectProductCol" class="col-sm-12 col-lg-5">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
        <mat-placeholder class="placeholder mr-3 mb-1">בחר סוג מוצר</mat-placeholder>
        <span class="ml-3" matSuffix matTooltip="סוג מוצר" matTooltipPosition='right'>
                                        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="selectCashierCol" class="col-sm-12 col-lg-5 order-first order-md-last">
    <div [@fade]="products.length > 0 ? 'active' : 'inactive'">
      <div class="d-flex flex-column">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
          <mat-placeholder class="placeholder mr-3 mb-1">בחר קופה</mat-placeholder>
          <span class="ml-3" matSuffix matTooltip="שם הקופה" matTooltipPosition="right">
                                            </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row d-flex justify-content-around mb-5">
  <div id="selectInsuranceCol" class="col-sm-12 col-lg-5" [@fade]="companies.length > 0 ? 'active' : 'inactive'">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
      <mat-placeholder class="placeholder mr-3 mb-1">בחר חברת ביטוח</mat-placeholder>
      <span class="ml-3" matSuffix matTooltip="שם חברת הביטוח" matTooltipPosition='right'>
                                    </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="addImageCol" class="col-sm-12 col-lg-5 text-center align-self-center">
    <div *ngIf="policyForm.get('firstPage.productType').value?.type !== 'executive' &&
                        policyForm.get('firstPage.productType').value?.type !== null ">
      <button mat-button type="button" id="uploadFileButton" class="form-upload-btn">
                                        <label>
                                            <input type="file" (change)="setFile($event.target)">
                                        </label>
                                    </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to replace the order of selectCashierCol and selectInsuranceCol cols on the mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the order of columns in separate rows because they don't share the same flexbox parent (the row). The solution is to put the columns in the *same* parent `.row`...

```
  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-around mb-5">
        <div id="selectProductCol" class="col-sm-12 col-lg-5 pb-5">
            <div class="d-flex flex-column">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                    <mat-placeholder class="placeholder mr-3 mb-1">בחר סוג מוצר</mat-placeholder>
                    <span class="ml-3" matSuffix matTooltip="סוג מוצר" matTooltipPosition='right'>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="selectCashierCol" class="col-sm-12 col-lg-5 order-first order-md-last pb-5">
            <div [@fade]="products.length > 0 ? 'active' : 'inactive'">
                <div class="d-flex flex-column">
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                        <mat-placeholder class="placeholder mr-3 mb-1">בחר קופה</mat-placeholder>
                        <span class="ml-3" matSuffix matTooltip="שם הקופה" matTooltipPosition="right">
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="selectInsuranceCol" class="col-sm-12 col-lg-5" [@fade]="companies.length > 0 ? 'active' : 'inactive'">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                <mat-placeholder class="placeholder mr-3 mb-1">בחר חברת ביטוח</mat-placeholder>
                <span class="ml-3" matSuffix matTooltip="שם חברת הביטוח" matTooltipPosition='right'>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="addImageCol" class="col-sm-12 col-lg-5 text-center align-self-center">
            <div *ngIf="policyForm.get('firstPage.productType').value?.type !== 'executive' &&
                        policyForm.get('firstPage.productType').value?.type !== null ">
                <button mat-button type="button" id="uploadFileButton" class="form-upload-btn">
                    <label>
                        <input type="file" (change)="setFile($event.target)">
                    </label>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

https://codeply.com/p/n4mw1Vydsy

Comment: added to this solution custom order with media queries for the mobile and it's working, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

According to bootstrap version 4's grids system, you have a bootstrap class "order-(here you can set the order number from 1 to 12)" like order-2 which means that respective div will be placed on second number. The default value of order is 0, so if you haven't added any order class to a specific div, then it will be ordered firstly.
You can also set the order differently for different breakpoints like if you want a div to be placed on 1st order in desktop view but should be placed at the last in mobile view you can assign two classes to it like this: order-lg-1 order-12.

**Note:** This order class will only work with divs having column class, it will not work for parent row containers.

For complete documentation, please visit bootstrap's site: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Answer (score -1):

I think what you’re looking for is just the css order property. There is a great example of this on MDN. And the cool part is this is built into CSS itself so if you end up not using the bootstrap library you could still use this property. Really cool stuff!

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order

I hope this helps.

Comment: I think it's the same as bootstrap order or maybe bootstrap using this also but i tried it and it did not work. I could only change cols in same rows but not in different rows.